# Calculating Taylor coefficients by fitting

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

I want to compute numerically the Taylor series coefficients of some (real analytic) function that appears in a problem I am looking at, let's say $ f(x) = \sum_{n\ge0}f_n x^n $.

I can do two things:

1. I have a way to compute $f(x_i)$ for any positive real $x_i<1$. This is a relatively quick computation and it can be done with arbitrary precision. I can do that for a "large" number of points (say something like 1000).
2. I have a way to compute directly any "f_n" with arbitrary precision, but this becomes very slow very quickly as $n$ increases. So realistically I can only compute a handful of $f_n$'s (say 10).

An obvious method to do that, is to calculate the first 10 coefficients and then get points of the form $p_i=(x_i,f(x_i))$ and fit the truncated Taylor series for the "rest".

Is there any better method than this obvious one? Is there any rule of thumb about the precision I need for $p_i$'s if I want a given precision of $f_n$'s?
How many $f_n$'s is it reasonable to expect to calculate accurately (for some given precision)?

Comment: How large is $n$ ?

Comment: Well, that's basically one of my questions. Assuming fixed precision, what would be a realistic expectation for $n$?

Comment: I suppose you are aware of the difference between a truncated Taylor series and an interpolating polynomial, are you ?

Comment: You should have a look at the Staviskiy-Golay fiters for numerical derivatives. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter

Comment: @GCab I do know the difference, but as I said, I don't know any other way to do that.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks, I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

Rather than an answer this is just to make my comment more understandable, and I need some lines for that.

I entangled in a similar problem and  had to make clear to myself that:
- the (truncated) Taylor series is a polynomial "osculating" (that has the highest contact order) the function at $x=0$, or any other fixed $x_0$;
- the interpolating polynomial exactly matches the function at various different values of $x$ at discrete distance from each other.

That is, in the  Taylor polynomial the interpolation points are infinitely close to each other, and, for a finite degree,  it will never interpolate **exactly** other points at finite distance from $x_0$.
In the reverse, it also means that an interpolating polynomial will never 
provide you the **exact** Taylor coefficients, except for the initial term $f(x_0)$.
The bounds on error will be given by the various Remainder formulations, and thus depend on the actual $f(x)$ being considered.

A classical example is $e^x$.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer but I think it is useful to have it here, so I upvoted it